# High Performance Cluster Virtualization required in Hadoop on Mesos

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, virtualization, mesos

Our department at work just bought 4 nodes (servers) each with 80 cores and a bunch of memory and disk space.

We are just in the beginning stages and want to make sure that the nodes are brought into a cluster correctly for what we will want to use it for as well as future use.

Anticipated use is focused on machine learning/ big data. Essentially we are the advanced analytics team. We have SQL servers and databases setup for the full data. Our primary objective is to use the data to gain business insights, develop algorithms, and build optimization engines for the data and processes for the org. Tools we might need at some point:

```
-Docker images for developed applications 
-Place to run jobs when developing new algorithms in batch job/maybe real time.
-Python ML algorithms
-Spark Jobs
-Possible Hadoop cluster? (this one uncertain about now)
```

-We want to run batch jobs, but also interactive jobs.

Our current plan is to run Chronos and eventually Marathon as well for the scheduling. We plan on Apache Mesos for the resource management.

Finally to the question. Our IT department informed us that to run a hadoop cluster, we have to virtualize each node. This virtualization takes up 8 cores on each node as well as GBs of memory and a ton of disk space. Are they correct? What way can we reduce the overhead of our system so we aren't consuming 10-20% of our resources in setting up the server?

Finally, as an added bonus, are there good books on setting up a mesos cluster, adding hadoop, and configuring everything.

Based on some comments, maybe we don't need Hadoop, in which case we wouldn't need virtualization.

Comment: Not really clear why you'd use Mesos for Hadoop now that Hadoop/YARN supports all those jobs you listed. Oozie can be used in place of Chronos... In any case, it's not clear either why you'd need Hadoop, as you can use any other shared filesystem rather than HDFS. But yes, virtualizing in general should dedicate much more than 10% of a node to something like Hadoop

Comment: would be a pretty small hadoop cluster, depending on the actual use cases, do you need hdfs or yarn?  if you are looking at clustered storage you might better looking at something like ceph (which would give you a clustered storage) then running mesos with spark would give you 3/5 of the things you mentioned.

Comment: Cricket_007, I don't know much about clusters and hadoop in general. Maybe that is where I need to learn more. Anyway, do you have to virtualize in hadoop? Or is that just needed since we don't currently have a dedicated systems for things like master, slave, config. I'll update the question for primary uses.

Comment: shainnif, so we would get spark, docker, and python but not Hadoop and a testing environment?